# Fatal Error Call to a member function dispatch() while call my Block in magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento-2.0

This is my Block File:

```
 <?php

 namespace ChennaiBox\Mymail\Block\Mail;

 class MailContent extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {
 protected $_objectManager;

 protected $customerSession;

 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,  
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
 ) {
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
  }

 public function mymailData()
 {
try{

     if ($this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
     $cutomerEmail    =(string)$this->customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();

     echo $cutomerEmail;

      else{
            $this->_redirect('customer/account/login/');
          }
   }catch (Exception $e) {

        $e->getMessage();

    }
   }

 }
```

If I call this block I get error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function dispatch() on null in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php
>   on line 642, referer:
>   http://magentodev.gworks.mobi/magento2/customer/account/index/

from apache `error.log` file., why, suggect me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The problem is that your constructor does not match the parent class constructor.

To fix that you need to update your constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,  
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    array $data = []
 ) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
  }
```

Don't forget to flush the `var/cache` and `var/generation` after your changes.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me with one of those 'I know I'm forgetting something but I can't remember what' situations.