# Create a helper in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, helper

I am trying to create a helper that i can use from a few blocks i have extended however am getting errors.

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Promotion extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper{


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


    public function testFunc() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Following error shows on page load:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in /mage/root/path/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:644\n
```

I am running in developer have cleared the var/generation folder however still i get this error. I have tried adding construct however get a range of different errors doing so wanted some advice on here about where i have gone wrong?

My helper function is being called using below code from blocks:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class CategoryPromote extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
public function __construct(\Vendor\Module\Helper\Promotion $promote) {
    $this->promote = $promote;
}

public function getSale() {
    $this->promote->testFunc();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add namaspace then use file as i mention below, i am sure it will work for you

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Promotion extends AbstractHelper
{

 public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);

    }

}
```

Block file should like this

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\YourBlockPath;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Vendor\Module\Helper\Promotion as HelperData;

class Condition
    extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView
{
    /**
     * @var HelperData
     */
    protected $_hlp;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct,
    HelperData $helperData,
    array $data = []
) {
        $this->_hlp = $helperData;

        parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $arrayUtils,
        $data
    );
    }

}
```

You can see in Abstractview there in __construct function and you should have 3 params along with data like

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
        array $data = []
    ) {
}
```

so once you extend this class parent construct function should received params as same in child class.

Hope this is good to understand.

Comment: Why you repeat my answer?

Comment: @PYYick, i am not repeating it, my answer id different then you. please check, also it is common thing to use helper in m2 framework. you are new to this forum i think, i am using it since more then 4 year so i know all rules

Comment: OK it's not about how long you and I stay here. I don't think it matters. Of course it's a better practice in coding.

Comment: Same error guys

Comment: yes it's not about stay but  see answer is totally different then yours. so you don't have any rights to say  or written this comment.

Comment: OK anyway we fall into the same fate finally. Look at @Harri comment

Comment: @Harri, My answer is updated, It looks like you have error on your block not in helper to use as i stated above

Comment: This seems very differnt to my block just trying to wrap my head around what is going on. Is it supposed to not extend \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View anymore?

Comment: hi
use this 
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView
{
to get all function from product view block

Comment: Ok im getting error Notice: Undefined variable: helperData. I changed use Vendor\Module\Helper\Promotion as HelperData;

Comment: Added HelperData $helperData, into construct and now i think its loaded will check.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, just wondering if you can explain why i need the extra classes and bits in use / construct? And how did you work that out?

Comment: @Harri, Glad to share with you. see my updated answer to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the time. I prefer to understand rather than just copy and paste just means i ask less question and more answers. So basically i look in the class ive extended from: and copy almost exactly except for within construct function i use parent::__construct($parentdependecy1, $parentdependency2 ,etc );

Comment: Also "use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;" Im unsure why these have been used here?

Comment: @Harri, thanks to share this, you can remove if not necessary for your. Or just pass this classes in construct with full path will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

You need to add Helper Context Object.

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Promotion extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper{


    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    array $data = []

    )
    {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }

    public function testFunc() {
    return "test";
    }
}
```

Then, add Context object to You Block.

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class CategoryPromote extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{

 protected $promote;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Promotion $promote,
    array $data = []
    ) {
    $this->promote = $promote;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
    }


public function getSale() {
    $this->promote->testFunc();
}
```

Then, remove `var/cache` , `var/generation` and check it.

Let me know, if you have issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply , i tried that, updated my helper in my answer to yours. Cleared var/generation and refreshed page however have the same error still.

Comment: @Harri   I update my answer add this then clear chache and generation then, check it.

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately getting the same error

Comment: Could it may be be the use of context within the block? My block extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View and previously i didnt have a construct. I have added teh construct just for the helper but wondering if i have to modify for parent class?

Comment: yes, you need to use context object, with in block object. go to `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View ` class and copy constrctor and paste  to exrtent block then run it.

Comment: Ok will do, does this override the old construct when added in? As previously block worked without a construct?

Comment: @ Harri I updated my answwer

Comment: 2 __construct ? great, just copied from my answer :(. please don't do it

Comment: @liyakat I am not that type of person, I know magento2.

Comment: This just gives the error cannot redeclare construct now.

Comment: @Harri you need to add block and helper Constructor then only, error will resolved. let me know if you have issue.

Comment: Are there supposed to be multiple __construct in block?

Comment: @Harri NO, why you need  multiple constructor?. I mentioned you need to add block context object to Block Constructor and helper Context Object to helper constructor.

Comment: It's just that's what your answer shows ?

Comment: @Harri sorry, my mistake ,  i copy you code and pasted block and block context object then post.

Comment: @Harri I updated my answer

Comment: Ok will try again yeah thought that may be case.

Comment: This gives: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\ListProduct::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Helper\\PostHelper, array given

Answer (score 1):

`\Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper::__construct` does not inject `$data`. So that your `__construct` should be:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Also on your block file:

```
public function __construct(
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Promotion $promote,
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
    $this->promote = $promote;
}
```

Of course you need to clear cache and delete the files in `var/cache` and `var/generation`

Ref: [Fatal Error Call to a member function dispatch() while call my Block in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112829/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-dispatch-while-call-my-block-in-magento)

Comment: Have tried this initially had the same error will give it another go tho.

Comment: If error persist please let me know

Comment: Yeah have been doing the cache and generation clearing but still getting the error.

Comment: Are you sure the error is related to this helper?

Comment: Not entirely. Im wondering if it could be the block that im calling the helper in. My block extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View and previously i didnt have a construct. I have added the construct just for the helper but wondering if i have to modify for parent class?

Comment: You need `parent::__construct` everytime you extend a class

Comment: This gives the error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\\Catalog\\Block\\Product\\View::__construct() must implement interface Magento\\Framework\\Url\\EncoderInterface, array given,

Comment: Most likely cache issue

Comment: Hmm i have cache disabled however , ive just been running bin/magento cache:flush to be sure tho also

Comment: Where did you extends `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View`?

Comment: Im not sure i even need to extend it anymore. Im going to do the logic in helper i think but originally logic was in the block i made. But then i realised im gonna have to repeat myself to do logic for categories and products so thought i should put in a helper. I think i just need to have product logic in helper.

Comment: You may need to inject block instance into helper if you intend to carry out logic on helper

Comment: What would you suggest as best way about this. What im going is just creating a sale percentage icon on products. This worked fine but wanted the logic in block. So i did this fine but then realised i had to make a new block for categories. Rather than repeat myself i thought id wack the main logic in helper to work out sales % there then have extended block code just pass the product to the helper?

Comment: In your case, I'd suggest you to inject value from block to helper. The helper just handle calculations. It don't need extra injections in helper and keep you changes minimal.